# how to get correct image width with jquery lazyload plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, lazy-loading

In lazyload you place images like this:

```
<img data-original=“img/example.jpg” src=“img/loader.gif”>
```

So when i use:
`$(selector).width()`

I get the width of the loader image ,instead of the width of the image i will load. 
I Cant find any callback on the plugin either.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont know if there is a better solution but what i did for now is load the original image with  a display:none style and i get the width from there.

Comment: This kind of nullifies any benefit of using Lazy Load plugin. How about just adding width and height attributes to the img tag?